# Dota 2 API (dota2api) library in Python

Tags: python, api

Does anyone have experience with the Dota 2 API library in Python called 'dota2api'? I wish to pull a list of 200 recent games filtered by various criteria. I'm using the get_match_history() request (see [link](http://dota2api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#dota2api.Initialise.get_match_history)). Here's my code:

```
import dota2api
key = '<key>'
api = dota2api.Initialise(key)
match_list = api.get_match_history(matches_requested=200)
```

I haven't specified any filters yet, since I can't even get the matches_requested argument to work. When I run this code, I get exactly 100 matches. I fact, no matter how I specify the matches_requested argument, I allways get 100 matches.

Does anyone know if I'm specifying the argument wrong or some other reason why it's working as intended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such rarely used libraries it is hard to get an answer here.

I have found [this issue](https://github.com/joshuaduffy/dota2api/issues/52) on the library's Github:

> You can't get more than 500 matches through get_match_history, it's
>   limited by valve api. One approach you can do is alternate hero_id,
>   like, requesting with account_id, hero_id and start_at_match_id (none
>   if first request), values assigned, this way you can get at least 500
>   matches of each hero from that account_id.

Probably that has since changed and now the parameter is ignored by the API completely. Try creating a new issue on the Github.